# Python: How to use class methods in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have the following class methods to parse an individual URL:

```
product = Product(links[0], user_agents)
result = product.parse()
```

and class code:

```
class Product:
    soup = None
    url = None

    def __init__(self, url, user_agents):
        self.url = url
        print('Class Initiated with URL: {}'.format(url))
        # Randomize the user agent
        user_agent = get_random_user_agent(user_agents)
        user_agent = user_agent.rstrip('\n')

        if 'linux' in user_agent.lower():
            sec_ch_ua_platform = 'Linux'
        elif 'mac os x' in user_agent.lower():
            sec_ch_ua_platform = 'macOS'
        else:
            sec_ch_ua_platform = 'Windows'

        headers = {
            
        }
        r = create_request(url, None, headers=headers, is_proxy=False)
        if r is None:
            raise ValueError('Could not get data')
        html = r.text.strip()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    def parse(self):
        record = {}
        name = ''
        price = 0
        user_count_in_cart = 0
        review_count = 0
        rating = 0
        is_personalized = 'no'

        try:
            name = self.get_name()
            price = self.get_price()
            is_pick = self.get_is_pick()
```

Now I want to call `parse()` in multiprocessing. How do I do it? For a single record I am doing like this:

```
product = Product(links[0], user_agents)
result = product.parse()
```

Comment: FWIW, that's a "normal" method, not a class method (which are noted by the `classmethod` decorator)

Comment: If you are ok with modifying `Product` so that `__init__` 1) Uses a default `user_agents` value that is fixed between all executions, and 2) It calls `self.parse`, then you can just do `multiprocessing.pool.Pool().map_async(Product, links)` (or using any other function in the `Pool` arsenal)

Comment: @DeepSpace that makes sense. I will change and update you.

Comment: @DeepSpace should not `map_async(Product, links)` be `map_async(Product.parse, links)`?

Comment: @DeepSpace I did this `result.extend(p.map(product.parse, links))` and it gives error: `TypeError: parse() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. `parse` has the following signature: `def parse(product_url):`

Comment: No. As I mentioned in my comment you should modify `init` to call `parse`, and also in your example `parse` doesn't accept any argument

Comment: I have changed the `parse()` signature as mentioned above and the constructor now only accepts `user_agents`. The issue is that when I run , the first process sends `self.user_agents` as blank and then rest of the processes gets the value from `self.user_agents`.

Comment: @DeepSpace I better try your approach.

Comment: @DeepSpace so basically the constructor have  2 parameters? `def __init__(self, user_agents,product_url):`?

Comment: with current class you may need function which gets `url` and it creates `product = Product(url,...)` and runs `return product.parse()` and this new function you can use `.map(new_function, links)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With currecnt class you may need to create function which gets `url` and it creates `product = Product(url,...)` and it runs `product.parse()` - and this new function you can use `.map(new_function, links)`

Something like this:

```
def check(url):
    product = Product(url, user_agents)
    result = product.parse()
    return result

for multiprocessing.pool.Pool() as p:
    results = p.map(check, links)
```